# How do I print out memory traces in such a way that it does not fill up my storage?

Tags: python, python-3.x, memory, storage, simulator

I am running an experiment where I am printing out memory traces in the following format:

0x12345 R for read and

0x12345 W for write.

The purpose is to feed them into a simulator called RAMULATOR, which will provide various statistics and parameters such as memory cycles, CPU cycles etc. In this way, we can calculate the statistics for going from one memory address location to another.

I am doing it for a memory size of 2^23.
However, when I try to print these out, naturally a lot of them are printed in the following manner:

0x12345 W

0x56789 R

.

.

.

0x09876 W, etc. The issue is, while these are just a few characters in each line, this takes up a LOT of space really quickly. A few gigabytes in a few minutes. Is there anyway I can tackle this issue? This code is written in Python.

Comment: Why would you use a format that's so wasteful of space? Even the most minimal amount of compression would reduce the space occupied by a factor of five or so.

Comment: A binary format to store this would need 3 bytes. As it is now it needs 10 bytes per entry.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz how else would I do it? I think the simulator takes in value in this format. I am using a simple python print function `print(f"0x{x:08x} R")` to do it.

Comment: @KlausD. as of now I am using `print(f"0x{x:08x} R")` to print it and then I store it in a file. How else do you recommend I do it? I am not that skilled technically, so I am having a hard time understanding.

Comment: @winterlyrock For example, you could just pass it through any compression library. There's simple support for things like [lzma compression](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/lzma.html#reading-and-writing-compressed-files) in python.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz but I would need to unpack it to feed it to the simulator and it would be back to its original size, correct?

Comment: @winterlyrock No. since you wouldn't unpack or feed all of it at once. At no time would the entire thing be back to its normal size.